# Test if string exist in File (with R)

Tags: r

I have several fairly large csv files (few millions lines), and I would like to know which one I need to load. Some of them hold `GOTCHASTR` some do not. Say I way to load only the ones which hold this string, how can I test if without loading all the files and testing afterwards.

I realize it looks like a `bash/grep` question but as R import some UNIX functionalities I am hoping that this can work. I am using Windows 7 + gnuWin32

Comment: With grep you can do `grep -l GOTCHASTR /your/dir`. It will list all files that contain this text. Add `-R` if you want it to be recursive (in a dir structure) and `-i` to ignore case.

Comment: Thanks you should have written it as an answer, it is much faster than the readline answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
patterns <- sapply(list.files("/your/dir", full.names=TRUE), FUN=function(x){
  grep("GOTCHASTR", readLines(x))
})
```

Comment: thanks, will it stop at the first occurance or will it read all the file ?

Comment: It will read the whole file. If you want it to stop at the first occurance, you can use the n argument of readLines to chunk it up and let it break if you have found the occurance.